# LTspice .MEAS doesn't unravel branch wrap

Tags: ltspice, phase

When doing AC analysis in LTspice, there is an option to unravel branch wrap (i.e. phase un-wrapping).

[image]

However, if we use .MEAS to find magnitude and phase, there is no option to unravel branch wrap, it is deselected by default when using .MEAS. For example, using this circuit,

[image]

the phase at around 20kHz found from the bode plot with unravel branch wrap ticked is

[image]

while the phase measured by .MEAS is

[image]

So, does anyone knows how to unravel branch wrap when using .MEAS?

Comment: Unfortunately that's a known limitation. [Exporting](https://groups.io/g/LTspice/topic/50271207) also doesn't work with unwrapped phase.